# PHP - MVC - Better way to prevent calling unwanted method in Controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I don't know if my question should be asked [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or not. Please let me know or move it/delete it if that is the case.

**Question:**

For the sake of learning, I'm making my own little MVC "library" for a very small personal website. Here is the process being used (please correct me if I'm not even close to doing it the right way):

- All requests (except images, etc.) get sent through index.php (boostrap file).
- The bootstrap file parses the request and extracts the controller and action, ex:

  http://www.Domain.com/Controller/Action/Argument1/Argument2/...

Where Controller is the controller, action is the method called on the controller. In this case, it would end up being: **Controller**->**Action** ( **Argument1**, **Argument2** );

Now, what if a user visits:

```
http://www.Domain.com/Controller/__destruct
```

or

```
http://www.Domain.com/Controller/__get/password
```

**Current solution(s):**

- Run the request through a $config->getURIFilter () method or something
- Do a check for method_exists () and is_callable (), etc.
- Don't have any methods in the controller that aren't for handling a request

**It just seems like this shouldn't be an issue to begin with and my design is wrong.**

**P.S.** I've already looked at plenty of good MVC PHP frameworks (CodeIgniter, Yii, CakePHP, Zend, Swiftlet, etc.)

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430181/acl-implementation) relevant. it is about access control in MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either make your Controllers only handle specific actions, e.g.

```
/controllers
 /user
  loginController.php
  logoutController.php
```

and then have classes that only do that one thing

```
class LoginController implements RequestHandler
{
    public function handleRequest(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        …
    }

    private function someAuxiliaryMethod() {
        …
```

so that example.com/user/login will create a new LoginController and call the interface method `handleRequest`. This is a Strategy Pattern.

Or - if you dont want to split your controller actions like this - suffix your actions with a word (Zend Framework does this):

```
class UserController
{
    public function loginAction() {
        …
```

and in your bootstrap you add the suffix and invoke those methods then.

Yet another option would be to introduce a Router that can map URLs to Controller Actions and which can optionally do sanitizing to filter out malformed URLs, e.g. strip underscores.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I love those elegant solutions. I've lurked here a lot and I'm glad I got an answer from you. I'm usually following your advice since I come here to search a lot for questions on good design, etc. and I prefer your methods personally. I think I might go with your first solution after reading more on the Stratgey pattern and do some reading on it as well. Thanks again. Edit: on 2nd thought, I like the 2nd one better for its simplicity and not having to make each controller a request handler (even though that's what a controller is anyway), seems like less work in each controller

Comment: @DanielElkins you are welcome. And happy to learn my ramblings on SO are useful to people. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you treat any method preceded with an underscore as a private method (just show a not found page when you do your method_exists check if it starts with an underscore).

Answer (score 0):

Just mark methods that you don't want to expose to your controller as private or protected.

Keep it simple!

Comment: in general yes, but wont work in the case of `__get` like the OP shows

Comment: `if(substr($method, 0, 2) == '__') { return; }`

Answer (score 0):

I rolled my own MVC structure once for the same reason you're doing it, and the way I solved this was simply making an architectural decision to prefix all routable controller actions with the word "action", ie:

```
public function actionGetData(){

}

public function actionUpdateSomething() {

}
```

etc.

The reasons I did this:

- You maintain full control over public/protected/private scope in your class without worrying about whether a method is inadvertently exposed via some URL.
- It makes the routable actions obvious to the programmer.  `public function actionDoSomething()` is clearly accessible via a public URL (`/controllerName/doSomething`), whereas `public function getErDone()` is not.
- You're not forced to jump through hoops to identify routable actions.  Simply prefix your incoming parameter with "action" and see if the method exists.  Fast and simple.

I found this worked really well.