# What`s better, a single class for admins and visitors or 2 classes Company and adminCompany?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class `Company`, this class has some methods to search, list, etc and is used for the visitors of my website. But I have a different class `adminCompany`, which works only, when there is an admin user logged in. This class has the other methods: `update_info_company()`, `delete_company()`, and whatever an admin can do

My questions are:

- Should I have a single class (Company) to do everything and just restrict access to some methods?
- Is this against the principles of OOP?.

PD: it`s just to keep cleaner and shorter classes.

Answer (score 2):

In OOP we have this thing: [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). It basically means that each class should have only one reason to change ( when extended ).

From your description it seems that the "Company" is both a separate entity (most likely, some variation on [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject)), which has distinct properties and can be created or removed. And then it also has aspects of factory, when it is used to find multiple instances of same object. *This seems like a mistake.*

You should separate the two aspects of this structure (I would assume that now you have `class AdminCompany extends Company{}` , which is part of the problem).

As for controlling which group of users can perform with tasks, you might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685039/727208) useful.