# When to use models vs service in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, service, laravel-5, eloquent

I have been using for a while but still I am confuse on what to include in my controllers specifically "When should I use Model and When to Use Service"?

I am confused if I am making the right thing.

Comment: Maybe you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595036/mvc-laravel-where-to-add-logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to never use models directly into the controllers.. Adopt the repository-pattern which enables the use of dependency injection of services into the controller.. Use Service Layer to contain the business logic.. In this way all the related codes would be onto similar layer.

**Reference for repository pattern:**
http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern#.VuJcVfl97cs

Comment: why is models called in services? does that make the process long?

Answer (score 3):

Please don't use model directly in your controller, unless if you are building a very simple application but for a large application, it would be good to use a repository. Kindly take a look at this tutorial https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/