# Laravel validation, how to test/TDD?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unit-testing, laravel-5.3

How should I organize validation in Laravel to be able to test/TDD?

I think I need to throw `ValidationException` from services instead of doing something in controllers, to be able to assert it in unit tests.

For example I have `changePassword($user, $password, $newPassword)` method in `UserService` where I need to check that `$password` is correct and that `$newPassword` is not empty, etc.

Should I do it like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23595760/964478? Create a validator via `Validator::make` somewhere and

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    throw new ValidationException($validator);
}
```

And in unit tests

```
public function should_not_change_password_if_incorrect_current_password()
{
    $user = ......;

    $this->expectException(ValidationException::class);

    $this->userService->changePassword($user, 'incorrect', 'newPassword');
}
```

Or there are better ways?

Or I should not unit test it and just do acceptance testing (checking HTTP response, session, ...)?

Comment: Validation at the service level? I do that in the controller where I'm handling the request. What's the advantage of doing it in the service?

Comment: @jcorry How do you test it? Only at the acceptance test level (like perform a POST request and check errors in response/session)? I tried to do it in unit tests. Also thought that some service methods may be used in several places, so it would avoid code duplication.

Comment: Yes, the controller code would be best tested with acceptance/integration tests. That's where you'd test the validation.

Answer (score -1):

You may wish to mock the Validation object, and in your mock you can provide simple behavior for a failed validation and assert against that behaviour.

You could use a tool like [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) to create simple mocks in your tests.