# Using Laravel as N tier Architecture

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I see MVC pattern here, I would like to know the best practice to active N-tier architecture in Laravel.

For example: Controller, Business Logic, Data Access layer (assuming Model in Laravel), Presentation Layer (DTO's used as JSON response)

[image]

Where do I fit Business Logic and DTO's in Laravel?

Comment: Your diagram already shows where to put the business logic (more or less).

Comment: I mean in Laravel where should I add that, means shall i create BL directory and and some classes, etc.?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Hence wanted an opinion on what is the best practice we can use in Laravel, or is there anything Laravel provides OOB to support this.

Comment: Asking for "best practices" is [not the best way to spend your time here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354).  The "best practice" is the one that most effectively meets your specific requirements.  Ask us about a specific problem you are having.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23595036/102937

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but I have already gone through the complete answer in detail before asking question here.

Comment: Then what are you confused about?  Standing up a BL folder and writing some classes is as good a strategy as any other.

Answer (score 1):

The business logic might be in many places on Laravel:

1. In the controller itself
2. In [Events and Event Listeners](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/events)
3. In Services
4. In [Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#creating-jobs) (queued or not)

There many ways to do it, it's up to you decide which fits to each case. If you try following [SOLID Principles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) you will fell the necessity to use some of this options.

For the presentation layer, you can use [Laravel API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources), since it provides a simple way to transform your data and output as JSON in a standardized format.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
My ideology is to not write logic in controllers.
I think, Logic in Events might not fit my requirements.
I will try out Services though
Also, jobs are useful but not the place where I am looking for,

Have read about API resources, will try it out that too.

So services and API resources is what I am thinking now.