# How can I execute 2 functions on 1 route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem,

I want my route **/browse** to both display some elements and check for one condition by a written function, these are two separate functions, but I want them to be running on one route, is it even possible?

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/browse',[PlantsController::class, 'browse'])->name('browse');
Route::get('check',[PlantsController::class, 'checkForWatering'])->name('check');
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
 public function browse()
{
    $this->checkForWatering();

    $this->displayPlants();
}
```

But in result it's a blank white page.

Here are my functions:

```
  public function checkForWatering()
{
    $all = DB::table('plants')
    ->select('*')
    ->get();  

    foreach ($all as $result)
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $nextWatering = (new Carbon ($result->watered_at))
        ->addDays($result->watering_frequency);            
        $daysPast = $nextWatering->diffInDays($now);

        $query = DB::table('plants')
        ->where('watering_frequency', '>=', $daysPast)
        ->get();
    
        $query->isEmpty() ? $result = true :  $result = false;
        return redirect()->route('browse')->with('result',$result);

    }
}


 public function displayPlants(){
    $now = new Carbon();

    $plants = DB::table('plants')
    ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->id())
    ->orderBy('watered_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

    foreach ($plants as $plant)
    {
        $plant->watered_at = Carbon::parse($plant->watered_at)
        ->diffForHumans();
        $plant->fertilized_at = Carbon::parse($plant->fertilized_at)
        ->diffForHumans();
    }

    return view('browse')->with('plants',$plants);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the view, change browse to:

```
public function browse() {
    $response = $this->checkForWatering();
    if (!empty($response)) {
         // If checkForWatering returned a response object, return it
         return $response;
    }
    return $this->displayPlants();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by calling the other controller method and assigning the response to a variable before returning it.

```
public function browse() 
{
    $response = $this->checkForWatering();
    // Checks if the Response of checkForWatering exists
    return !empty($response) ? $response : $this->displayPlants();
}
```

While you can call two Controller methods within another Controller method. Ideally you'd want to break the logic of these out of the controllers and into their own classes.

Software architecture is very subjective but I recommend taking a look into some resources about Controllers and how some people recommend laying them out within applications, I believe this will help you with regards to bumping your head with issues like these later down the line like wanting to call the same bit of code within two Controllers.

- [How much business logic should be allowed to exist in the
  controller](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26438/how-much-business-logic-should-be-allowed-to-exist-in-the-controller-layer)
- [MVC (Laravel) where to add logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595036/mvc-laravel-where-to-add-logic)
- [Keeping your Laravel applications DRY with single action classes](https://medium.com/@remi_collin/keeping-your-laravel-applications-dry-with-single-action-classes-6a950ec54d1d)
- [Put Your Laravel Controllers on a Diet](https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2018/02/18/put-your-laravel-controllers-on-a-diet/)