# Disallowing routed URLs

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

I am working on a personal MVC framework including a router for the URLs.

At the moment I have a PagesController and a 'sitemap' view. So I can go to url.com/pages/sitemap/

I have also set up URL Route for "/info/{page}/". I've done this for static pages that I want to have 'info' in their URL. This also works for sitemap.

Then, as intended, I have mapped /sitemap/ to the sitemap page as well.

I only want /sitemap/ to be a valid resource, what would be the best way to disable/redirect the other URLs

Comment: you might find answers in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3430181/727208) relevant to your current issue.

Comment: It's not really a permission issue, I just want to have a canonical URL and redirect the other ones..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the implementation of your router. If you have access, in the controller, to the original URL, you compare it and issue a redirect if needed:

```
class PagesController {

    function sitemap($request) {
        if ($request->url == '/info/sitemap/')
            $this->response->redirect('/sitemap/');

        //regular processing here
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Another option, if your rules are regex-based, to add an "exclude" pattern, that would make `/info/sitemap/` not match the `/info/{page}/` pattern.

Something along the lines of :

```
$router->add(array(
    'url' => '/info/(?<action>.*)/',
    'controller' => 'PagesController',
    'exclude' => '(?:sitemap)',
));
```

Comment: Yeah, seems like the best option. Perhaps I could give a 'disallow array' to the routed URL.

Comment: @GerbenJacobs or, you could define the rules but exclusively use only one URL.