# Show / hide links in MVC view based on permissions

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I understand [how to implement ACL and restrict access to controller methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430181/acl-implementation).

What I don't understand is how to display certain links only for users with certain permissions in the view? Could someone please demonstrate how this is done?

The only related answers I can find are specific to ASP which doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zend Framework as per that article, then use a view helper. Call the ACL class, set controller/user etc and return a boolean value.

```
<?php if ($this->acl()->hasPermissionToViewUri()): ?>
    // show uri
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: I'm not using Zend, it's for a custom framework so I'm seeking any answers in general. Seeing how other frameworks do it is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
if(user->logged_in()){
    $data = array( 'link' => $link1);
} else {
    $data = array( 'link' => $link2);
}

View::make('some-view)->with($data);
```

In the view:

```
  <?php echo $link; ?>
```

This princip you have to transfer to your mvc framework.

Comment: But, technically I'm told that the controller isn't supposed to pass data to the view, as that breaks the one-way flow of the pattern.

Answer (score -2):

I always create a function on Yii (the framework I use) to check access to see or get into some stuff.

In Yii I use it like this:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('restricted_zone')) {
    echo 'hurray i have access!';
} else {
    echo 'do not have access! :(';
}
```

as used in a Yii extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rbam/

You can use it everywhere you want to restrict something - model, view, controller and even in auxiliary classes you may import.

You just need to be sure that your class is ready to be used all along your code.

Comment: And so what? That's excellent, as you can access it through all the application. I think it's an excellent approach.

Comment: Why not? Would you suggest using one function for each controller? What about reusing code guys? I would love to hear facts from you.

Comment: Probably you've never seen the way Yii rbam extension is made: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rbam/

Comment: +1.  Global scope is bad because you never know who may have modified a global value or when.  If you use a **static class** (much different and much better than a global variable) *purely* for data access and never for mutation, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it and @IvoPereira's arguments are entirely valid.

Comment: The Magento framework uses a pattern similar to this and Magento is a powerhouse of, in fact, *too many* solid design patterns & system architecture.  It's notorious for having an extremely high learning curve because its system is so heavily designed and abstracted.  This is one thing they are not doing wrong.

Comment: @JMTyler: I'm pretty sure you can see that `Yii:app()` actually behaves like a global variable here, so please, don't troll too much.

Comment: Dude, you've got 8 years experience and  you think global scope is 'excellent'?

Comment: @hakre: Not trolling.  I agree that having public access to `Yii::app()->user` is no good, but the general concept stands.  Replace that with something like `Yii::app()->getUser()` and there's no danger.

Comment: I would invite you guys to look through the Yii framework and to check how the methods are being called, all the process.

Comment: @IvoPereira: I try hard to not use a PHP framework as an excuse for something. Instead I try to find the PHP framework that allows me to make less excuses.

Comment: Fortunately, Yii "allows me to make less excuses" :) That's why I started working with it!