# redirect users to different pages based on role php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to redirect users to different pages based on the roles given to them in the database. Only the username and password is submitted on the login page. I have to fetch the role from the database which looks like this:

```
username  |  password  |  role
xxxxxx       xxxxxx       admin
xxxxxx       xxxxxx       trainer
xxxxxx       xxxxxx       trainer
xxxxxx       xxxxxx       Line Manager
```

Here is my code:

```
// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 


$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

     // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
     $role = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


      if($role == "Admin"){
        header("location:index.php");
            exit();
      }
      elseif($role['role'] == "Trainer"){
  header("location:index1.php");
        exit();
     }
      elseif($role['role'] == "Line Manager"){
  header("location:index2.php");
        exit();
     }
      elseif($role['role'] == "Client"){
  header("location:client.php");
        exit();
     }


  }
     else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
     }
?>
```

Comment: ok tell us more. that seems to work ok, i would use a switch block instead of the if

Comment: Read up on [ACL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) to get a better idea of what you need to do. Also, it isn't clear what you are asking us here as there is no actual question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ACL implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430181/acl-implementation)

Comment: header location should URI. not a file name. use that file with base url.

Comment: it doesnt work, the page remain, without any redirection, could you show me how the switch block would work with my codes

Comment: So debug it! check if count = 1, then check what you have in the role variable and see why it is not matching what you expect it to do. Try echoing or print_r() ing some of your data

Comment: The first `if` checks `$role` while the others check `$role['role']`. You probably want the latter

Answer (score 3):

In your code, the first `if` statement checks `$role` while the others check `$role['role']`. My guess is that you're trying to log in as "Admin" and that's why it's not working.

### Update

There was far more wrong with your code than I initially realized.

1. You're mixing mysql_* functions with mysqli_* functions. Not only is this wrong, but mysql_* functions have been deprecated. [You should no longer use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).
2. You're leaving yourself open to SQL Injection by using POST variables directly in your select statement. The way to fix this is by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

> **Disclaimer:** I haven't used mysqli in quite some time so the code presented here may contain errors.

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select database.
$db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if( $db->connect_errno ){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

if ($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT role FROM login WHERE `username`=? and `password`=?")) {
    /* bind parameters for username and password */
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $myusername, $mypassword);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
    
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
        // bind the result to a variable
        $stmt->bind_result($role);
        $stmt->fetch();
        
        switch( $role ){

            case 'Admin':
                header("location:index.php");
                exit();

            case 'Trainer':
                header("location:index1.php");
                exit();

            case 'Line Manager':
                header("location:index2.php");
                exit();

            case 'Client':
                header("location:client.php");
                exit();

            default:
                echo "Wrong Username or Password";
        }
    
    }

    $stmt->close();
}

$db->close();

?>
```

I personally prefer [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (illustrated below). I haven't tested the code so it too may not be completely accurate, but it should get you on the right path.

```
<?php
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

try {
    // Connect to server and select database.
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    
    $stmt = $db->("SELECT *, COUNT(*) as count FROM login WHERE `username`=:user and `password`=:pass");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $myusername);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $mypassword);
    
    if ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $count = $row['count'];
        
        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table must be 1 row
        if ($count == 1) {        
            switch( $row['role'] ){

                case 'Admin':
                    header("location:index.php");
                    exit();

                case 'Trainer':
                    header("location:index1.php");
                    exit();

                case 'Line Manager':
                    header("location:index2.php");
                    exit();

                case 'Client':
                    header("location:client.php");
                    exit();

                default:
                    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
            }
        }
    }
    
    $db = null;
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}

?>
```

For more on PDO, see: [Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Comment: it will trigger the default even though my username password is right

Comment: Please see my revised answer.