# Need an advice for design pattern

Tags: php, oop, object, design-patterns

I need an advice for my simple project. It's a logger system. I have the following files/classes

File - check if file exist is readable etc

ConfigParser - it's an abstract class of which I use the __construct method to do some things. The class is never instantiated directly. It's a decorator.

```
abstract class ConfigParser
{
    protected $filename;

    public function __construct($file)
    {
       // Here I want to invoke validate() method of File class
       // I know that I can do $file = new File(); $file->validate()
       // but the idea is to keep the things decoupled
       // Also I know that I can extend the File class ConfigParser extends File
       // but this doesn't make sence
       // I can pass the File object on child class new XmlParser('file.xml', $fileObj)
       // but this doesn't make sence too.
       // I don't want to use traits as it's bizarre for me

    }
}
```

XmlParser - extends ConfigParser

IniParser - extends ConfigParser

As the project goal is to keep the classes decoupled I can't figure out how to implement the File class in this scenario.

Comment: I wonder if this might be better suited at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might find this answer relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18682856/727208

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's such a nice design to do the validation in the constructor. A constructor should simply create the Parser and possibly do *simple* things.

What you could do would be using the template method pattern, then do the validation in the parent class and delegate the real parsing to the actual parser class.

```
abstract class ConfigParser {

  final function parse(){
     $file->validate();
     $this->conreteParse();
  }

  abstract function concreteParse();
}
```