# Prevent duplicate code with checking sessions

Tags: php, session

I have three session levels:

1. `session->is_logged_external`
2. `session->is_logged_admin`
3. `session->is_logged_staff`

I have a small function bellow (`checkLogin`) that I call to display a message if they do not have the session needed to accesses the page.

As you can see I have commented out code at a attempt to create a function that checks if the session is in one of these categories if so let them see page if not display message.

```
public function checkLogin()
    {
        $logged_admin = $this->session->is_logged_admin;
        //$logged_external = $this->session->is_logged_external;
        //$logged_staff = $this->session->is_logged_staff;

        if(!isset($logged_admin) || $logged_admin != TRUE) {
            echo 'Im sorry, you do not have administrator pillages';
            echo anchor('main/index', 'Return home');
            die();
        }
        //else if(!isset($logged_external) || $logged_external != TRUE) {
            //echo 'Im sorry, you do not have external pillages';
            //echo anchor('main/index', 'Return home');
        //}
        //else if(!isset($logged_staff) || $logged_staff != TRUE) {
            //echo 'Im sorry, you do not have staff pillages';
            //echo anchor('main/index', 'Return home');
        //}
    }
```

This did not work so I commented the code out. My next idea was to create three functions one for each of the sessions and call what functions I need for each page within the controller however, this is basically the same code repeated 3 times but with different session names, Is this the right way of doing this ?

Thanks guys.

**example of idea two**

**First Admin session function**

```
public function checkLoginAdmin()
    {
        $logged_admin = $this->session->is_logged_admin;
        if(!isset($logged_admin) || $logged_admin != TRUE) {
            echo 'Im sorry, you do not have administrator pillages';
            echo anchor('main/index', 'Return home');
            die();
        }
    }
```

**Second Staff session function**

```
public function checkLoginStaff()
    {
        $logged_admin = $this->session->is_logged_staff;
        if(!isset($logged_staff) || $logged_staff != TRUE) {
            echo 'Im sorry, you do not have staff pillages';
            echo anchor('main/index', 'Return home');
            die();
        }
    }
```

and a third that would be external, then I could call each one when I need them, right?

Comment: you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9685039/727208

Comment: Thank @tereško, ill check it out