# PHP MVC Authentication before call class and methods

Tags: php, authentication, model-view-controller

I tried to make PHP login and authentication system base on MVC. I even need some guide about how can I prevent to access all classes on controller/admin folder without proper login.

I have two ideas :
1- make constructor for all classes on admin folder and check for logged in session and then only allow calls to any other methods in that class.

2- add a secret word at the end of all methods name on my admin folder. Then all calls to those methods will redirected to __call function for check session and if that process done successfully then try to call admin's methods by adding that secret word.

I don't know which one is the better way or is there any other solution?

Comment: first method is the correct way to prevent access all classes without proper login.

Comment: Have you tried reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685039/727208

Comment: @Ayyappaamara no, it is not. It is actually a terrible idea, because it causes serious maintainability issues ... aside from the bad practice of placing logic on a constructor's code.

Comment: so finally constructor check auth session is better than __call system?